# Why Raspberry Pi 2 is not booting?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, tizen

I have flashed Tizen image into sd card and trying to boot Raspberry pi 2. But it is not booting.

- SD card Info : Samsung 16GB Class-10 microSD card.
- I have downloaded image from http://files.s-osg.org/tizen-on-rpi2/
- and flashed

  ```
    tizen-common-core-image-crosswalk-dev-raspberrypi2-20150811204400.rootfs.rpi-sdimg
  ```
- and

  ```
    tizen-common-core-image-crosswalk-dev-raspberrypi2.rpi-sdimg-2015-08-14
  ```

None of them are booting.

Is there any spec of SD card or anything am I missing?

Please help me.

Comment: First, I'll go with the images that does not have "...rootfs..." in the name, but it depends on what you want. I took the one on the very bottom that  has "...LATEST..." in the name. Also, how did you "flash" the image? Please take a look at this link: http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/04/bootable-image-for-tizen-on-raspberry-pi-2-released/

Comment: @Frederik Moller, I have followed same procedure. Image is flashed into SD card properly. But it is not booting after connecting with Raspberry pi2

Answer (score 1):

There were two separate problems:

- The SD card image was corrupted; the green ACT light had not been blinking. I re-formatted the SD card using SDFormatter and flashed it again.
- The HDMI to VGA cable had been faulty. I replaced it with an HDMI to VGA converter.

After addressing the above problems, it began working just fine.